# How would i shorten this command and repeat changing field number?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, cut

Command I am using is:

```
grep 'title' /tmp/ytdl/hre_find.text | cut -d">" -f3 | cut -d"<" -f1
```

and searches through text constructed this way:

```
uerls = soup.find_all(class_ = 'yt-lockup-title')
  with open('/tmp/ytdl/hre_find.text', 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(str(uerls))
```

Starting from field "3", output i want (song title) shows up at field "9", "15" (every 6), till the end of file.
How would i do this with awk and/or modify my recent solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a deleted comment, you would like to find

```
Queen - I Want to Break Free (Official Lyric Video)
```

from something like

```
a aria-describedby="description-id-187475" 
class="yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link" 
data-sessionlink="itct=CEoQ3DAYASITCKz-kJGviucCFQVisgodvkAP9jIGc2VhcmNoUgd3aGF0YmVy" 
dir="ltr" href="/watch?v=WUOtCLOXgm8" rel="spf-prefetch" 
title="Queen - I Want to Break Free (Official Lyric Video)"
```

You can use

```
grep -Eo 'title="[^"]*' tmp/ytdl/hre_find.text  | cut -d '"' -f2
```